# JavaScript "copy to clipboard" function doesn't work on ASP.NET server

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My Javascript code does this:

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(myVariable)
```

And it works great in my local environment but when I move it to an ASP.NET environment, the click event fires but the line above does not run, nothing is copied to clipboard. I thought it could be an environmental config issue but I'm kinda shooting in the dark.

Comment: So what browser? Any errors in the console? You need to provide debugging details

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard) shows a lot of limitations

Comment: @epascarello Running Chrome, latest version. No errors at all.

Comment: try: myVariable.execCommand('Copy');